# Есть ли альтернатива присваиванию через := в запросах?

Tags: mysql

Есть следующая задача.
Дано: Произвольная последовательность дат.
Задача: Необходимо объединить даты в пределах месяца в группы. То есть на выходе необходимо получить таблицу из двух колонок: Дата и наименование группы. При этом каждая дата может принадлежать строго к одной группе.
Например,
Дано:

```
Даты:
01.01.2018
15.01.2018
03.02.2018
```

На выходе мы должны получить:

```
Дата          Группа
01.01.2018    01.01.2018 - 15.01.2018
15.01.2018    01.01.2018 - 15.01.2018
03.02.2018    03.02.2018 - 03.02.2018
```

То есть мы берем первую дату и задаем некий интервал от этой даты и месяца после нее. Все даты, попадающие в этот интервал и будут относиться к первой группе. Далее мы берем самую раннюю дату, которая не входит в предыдущий интервал и также формируем следующую группу.

Еще пример:
Дано:

```
Даты:
2020-01-01 
2020-01-12
2020-01-23
2020-02-14
2020-02-25
2020-03-06
```

Результат:

```
Дата       Группа
2020-01-01 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-23
2020-01-12 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-23
2020-01-23 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-23
2020-02-14 2020-02-14 - 2020-03-06
2020-02-25 2020-02-14 - 2020-03-06
2020-03-06 2020-02-14 - 2020-03-06
```

Я могу решить эту задачу, с помощью использования переменных @  и присваивания через :=.
Но mysql 8 при выполнении таких запросов пишет, что в следующих релизах будет убрано присваивание через :=.  Поэтому я пытаюсь найти какой-то альтернативный вариант. Мой выбор пал на оконные функции.

Но через оконные функции у меня получилось сделать только с наложением групп друг на друга.То есть:

```
Дата          Группа
01.01.2018    01.01.2018 - 15.01.2018
15.01.2018    15.01.2018 - 03.02.2018
03.02.2018    03.02.2018 - 03.02.2018
```

Код запроса:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  nextdate
, CONCAT(FIRST_VALUE(nextdate) OVER w, LAST_VALUE(nextdate) OVER w) AS group_name
FROM test_table
WHERE nextdate IS NOT NULL
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY nextdate RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL 1 month FOLLOWING)
```

Очень прошу вашей помощи, так как уже несколько дней не могу придумать решение и уже готов сдаться и вернуться к @a:=...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111156/discussion-on-question-by-sergey-ivashevich-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно через эмуляцию цикла через рекурсию. Но я это не могу рекомендовать, потому как перебор большого количества записей таким способом может быть очень медленным. Идея в том, что бы пронумеровать записи по порядку и в рекурсии цеплять к записи следующую за ней и анализировать даты ...

```
WITH RECURSIVE Tab AS(
    SELECT ts, row_number() over(order by ts) RN FROM test
), Rec AS(
    select ts, ts start, 1 RN from Tab where RN=1
  union all
    select T.ts,
           case when T.ts <= R.start+interval 1 month then R.start else T.ts end,
           T.RN
      from Tab T, Rec R where T.RN=R.RN+1
)
select ts, start, max(ts) over(partition by start) end
  from Rec
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43c899e83d37f5e9f28a6bb270785be9)

Для некоторого ускорения работы возможно поможет получение в первой части следующей за текущей даты (lead()) и использование в рекурсивной части исходной таблицы по условию равенства дат, по индексу это возможно быстрее, чем работа с виртуальным номером строки, который не проиндексирован. Но не факт ...

Comment: интересное решение. Спасибо большое.